# How to extract text from PDF using PDFExtStream using Java

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-extraction, pdftextstream, snowtide

Text is not extracted from [Sample.pdf](https://app.box.com/s/n5fhwjp1wtl8hqoi7nra) file by using [pdftextstream-2.6.3.jar](https://app.box.com/s/t10ac6kln7cr1ra56nja)

```
String filePath = "D:\\inbox\\temp\\Sample.pdf";
File document = new File(filePath);
StringBuffer pdfText = new StringBuffer(1024);
com.snowtide.pdf.OutputTarget tgt = new com.snowtide.pdf.OutputTarget(pdfText);
PDFTextStream stream = new PDFTextStream(document);
stream.pipe(tgt);
stream.close();
```

Comment: That file contains correctly encoded text ("Audit Case #0035") so you must be doing something wrong. Merely stating "it does not work" *is not a question*.

Comment: @Jongware It is working for another pdf documents, but not working for the attached pdf document.

Comment: Define "not working"! Do you get an error, no text, no result at all, doesn't your program start, does it say "cannot find this file" ...???

Comment: Your jar has been released in May 2013. Have you checked whether there is an update available?

Comment: I just tested your code using the current library version 3.1.1, it failed. Your code has been marked as deprecated, though, so I tested with the current sample; that also failed. iText, PDFBox, and PDFClown, on the other hand, all succeeded.

Comment: @mkl: Still in the dark :P What does "it failed" mean? Do you get an error message, or 'nothing', or not what you expected? The first text stream contains some binary data in an inline image (`BI..EI`) and unfortunately, at the time my own parser cannot handle this gracefully. Not sure if that is also with pdftextstream.

Comment: @Jongware *What does "it failed" mean?* - it extracts merely 3 empty lines. Maybe the inline images indeed are tripping stones here. Unfortunately PDFxStream is not open source, so I could not debug into it.

Comment: @Jongware Download [Sample.pdf](https://app.box.com/s/n5fhwjp1wtl8hqoi7nra) file paste it under  `D:\\inbox\\temp\\ ` folder. D drive -> inbox folder -> temp folder].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earlier today, we released [PDFxStream v3.1.2](http://snowtide.com/downloads). This is a bugfix release that includes a fix for the issue you encountered here.

In the future, please do get in touch with us directly if you have any difficulties, at help@snowtide.com; we do everything we can to support our customers and users.

Comment: The OP never got to name his issue -- all he said was, "hey I dunno, fix this for me". Can you expand on what it exactly fixed, so we can point out this new version for other questions with a similar problem?

Comment: Prior revisions of PDFxStream contained a set of errors in the bundled Adobe Glyph List mapping; it's rarely used, but the net result was that text extracts were effectively empty (linebreaks only, no "real" characters).